# Setting value of Observable not updating in view

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I have a bunch of Point objects(markers on google maps), I setup a click event listener that will set the global variable "currentPlace" equal to the Point object that's being clicked then i wrap currentPlace in an observable hoping that the view will change, such as a side menu that will display info of that Point object.

```
"use strict";
var currentPlace;
...

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    zoom: 12,
    center: center,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: true,
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
      var viewModel = new ViewModel(collection);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
}

var Point = function(place) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = place.name;
    self.pos = place.pos;
    self.type = place.type;
    self.description = place.description;
    self.clicked = map.getZoom();
    /**
        Create a marker for this destination.
  */
    self.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.pos,
        title: place.name,
        icon: image,
        optimized: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
    /**
        Toggle for the visibility of each marker on map.
  */
  self.isVisible.subscribe(function(currentState) {
    if (currentState) {
      self.marker.setMap(map);
    } else {
      self.marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });

  self.isVisible(true);

  /**
        To re position the target marker and the map view to compensate for the shifted map view panel when the search menu pushes in from the left when the location is being clicked on the menu.
  */
    self.focusSearch = function() {
        map.setZoom(16);
        map.setCenter(self.marker.position);
        map.panBy(200,0);
        self.open();
    }
    /**
        To re position the target marker and the map view to compensate for the shifted map view panel when the menu slides in from the left when the location is being clicked on the menu.
  */
    self.focus = function() {
        map.setZoom(16);
        map.setCenter(self.marker.position);
        map.panBy(-200, 0);
        self.open();
    }
    /**
        Display the name and a brief description of the location in a infowindow for the corresponding marker. Also checks if the map view, in this case the zoom level has changed, if so then change the map view and re center it to the marker of the loaction that is selected. Applies to only when the regular menu is active.
    */
    self.open = function() {
        var contentString = "<h2>" + place.name + "</h2><br>";
        infowindow.setContent(contentString + place.description);
        infowindow.open(map, self.marker);
    }
    /**
        Dismiss the infowindow.
    */
    self.close = function() {
        infowindow.close();
        self.marker.setAnimation(null);
    }
    /**
        Additional event listeners for the marker.
    */
    self.marker.addListener("mouseover", function() {
        self.open();
        self.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    });

    self.marker.addListener("mouseout", function() {
        self.marker.setAnimation(null);
    });

    self.marker.addListener("click", function() {
        currentPlace = self;
        map.setZoom(16);
        map.setCenter(self.marker.position);
        pushLeft.close();
        slideLeft.close();
        slideBottom.open();
        self.open();
    });
}
/**
        This is our ViewModel that handles displaying a menu of destinations, filter/search through the menu and finally displaying markers of these destinations on the map.
*/
var ViewModel = function(list) {
    var self = this;
    /**
     * Create a Place object for each object in the initial array and
     * place them in a new observable array.
    */
    self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray(list.map(function(place) {
        return new Point(place);
    }));

    self.search = ko.observable("");
    currentPlace = self.allPlaces()[0];
    self.selected = ko.observable();


    /**
     * Filter locations out of the menu view for any unmatched results.
     * Filter by name, description and type.
    */
    self.searchResult = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        var q = self.search().toLowerCase();
        return self.allPlaces().filter(function(place) {
            return ((place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0));
        });
    });
    /**
     * Filter markers out of the map view for any unmatched results.
     * Filter by name, description and type.
    */
    self.filterMarkers = ko.computed(function () {
    var q  = self.search().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.allPlaces(), function (place) {
        var doesMatch = ((place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0));
        place.isVisible(doesMatch);
        return doesMatch;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is `currentPlace` global, and why is it not an observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout doesn't work that way. The only way to tie the GUI to your view model is to use an observable directly.

In your case, the best thing to do would be to move your global currentPlace variable into the view model as an observable. In order to access it later, create a global instance of your view model.

```
var vm = new ViewModel();

// Later on, access currentPlace this way:
vm.currentPlace();
```

Comment: You were right! Turns out i only needed 3 extra lines of code to make it work. declare var viewModel in the outermost scope so that the Point object can have access to it. Then inside viewModel do self.selected = ko.observable(self.allPlaces()[0]); to set the initial selected object which is essential because if I leave the observable empty, the view model will throw an error as i'm binding selected to the html. lastly, in the marker click even listener, add viewModel.selected = self so that the selected observable will be updated everytime a marker is clicked. Thanks!